# Does the scope of css include special elements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

css causes some red boxes that cannot be understood.

Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Linux x86_64

code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flow</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/b.css">
    <style>
        /* aaaaaaaaaa */
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        *:not(body):not(p) {
            color: red;
            font: 18px serif;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
            display: block;
            border: 1px red solid;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-z6wf15?file=index.html

Is this a bug?

Comment: The reason is because you are putting <html> and <body> tags in your stackblitz - in stackblitz you just include the contents of your body

Comment: I tried it and the same after removing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"special" doesn't have any defined meaning in HTML or CSS terms.

`*:not(body):not(p)` will select all elements that aren't the `body` or a `p` including `html`, `head` `meta`, etc.

Comment: Why is the content of the style tag displayed?

Comment: @Login — Because you set it to `display: block`

Comment: What I mean is that these things should not take effect. Elements of the head type should not be rendered either. No matter what I set.

Comment: @Login — You're wrong. If you tell it to make the `head` or `style` visible the it will. If you don't want that, don't write code which does that. Using a descendant combinator so you only target the descendants of the body element would probably be a good start.